# Opening huge text file, unicode issue

Tags: python, text, unicode, python-3.x

I'm trying to open a text file and print it's first line.

My code is:

```
dataFile = open('data/AllData_2000001_3000000.txt', 'r', encoding="latin-1")
print(dataFile.read(1000))
```

The input is

```
The bug is hitting
```

My output is

```
ÿþT h e  b u g  i s  h i t t i n g
```

also **iso-8859-1** give the same result.
When I try **utf-8** I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

What is my mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the Python version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `ÿþ` is likely the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) in a `UTF-16` file.  Try specifying that as your encoding when opening it.

Comment: It almost certainly is, so +1 for you

Comment: Great, that was the answer for the second question. I edit the question, sorry for that.