# Regular Expressions and SQL Server Error Logs - All false results

Tags: python-3.x

Ok,  I have done my searching and I have tried many things.  I think it is time to put my question here:

I have been working on taking in other user's SQL Server error logs, parsing out the rows into columns, then bulk inserting the data 1000 at a time. I troubleshoot SQL Server for other people so sp_readerrorlog will only show me my local instance. Finding root cause involves 4 sets of logs (SQL Server, Application Event, System Event, and get-clusterlog outputs and matching up timestamps. A fast load into SQL Server along with the ability to pull the exact timeframe needed will shorten my time spent staring at log files.

I am currently bottlenecked in testing the rows with a regular expression, which does work if I feed it data myself:

```
def sqlrowmatch(row):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d')

    if pattern.search(row):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

given any string that matches above (1111-11-11 11:11:11.11) will return as true. The idea is if in a SQL Server Error Log, if this is matched, then it is a separate entry.  this will allow memory graphs, deadlock graphs, and dumps to all be grouped in one entry as opposed to being split over several lines.

However, if I point it at one of the SQL Error Logs, there seems to be extra characters. This is giving re.match and re.show a hard time finding a match. If I load any line in this function,sqlrowmatch(), it reports back false for all rows.

ÿþ <-- this appears to be the first 2 characters at the first line.   re.search just doesn't even find it anywhere in the in the different elements.

False is what is returned if I put the function in with the 'with open' as statement:

```
with open(file, 'r') as sqllog:
    for line in sqllog:
        print(sqlrowmatch(line))
```

the first line should always be true if sqlrowmatch() is used.

> 2018-10-13 22:40:09.41 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2-GDR) (KB4458621) - 13.0.5201.2 (X64)

So I am lost and my current project is at a halt.  Perhaps some seasoned insight from this group can get me going again.

TIA

Comment: Interesting enough, I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176475/opening-huge-text-file-unicode-issue

open should be done with encoding='utf-16'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting enough, I found my answer here: [Opening huge text file, unicode issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176475/opening-huge-text-file-unicode-issue)

open should be done with encoding='utf-16'

It now matches appropriately